# Date and value conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm Inserting the ID's from table2 which is not exist in the table1. Table1 have perfect datatype in date(datetime), Gen(varchar(1)) but Table2 has different datatype for the same column date(varchar(255)), Gen(float) 1-M,2-F.
I share the problem in sample set.

Table1

```
  ID  date                  Gen
    193 1996-03-26 00:00:00 M
    446 1997-09-20 00:00:00 F
    689 1997-02-21 00:00:00 F
    612 1993-10-19 00:00:00 M
```

Table2

```
ID  date                    Gen
123 1993-03-02 00:00:00     1
456 2019-10-19 11:50:13.913 2
689 1997-02-21 00:00:00     2
789 2019-11-04 08:06:36.71  1
012 2000-10-02 07:11:19     1
```

I need to append the new ID's in table1. while using the insert query how can I convert the date and Gen variable like table1 format.

Result:
Table1

```
  ID  date                  Gen
    193 1996-03-26 00:00:00 M
    446 1997-09-20 00:00:00 F
    689 1997-02-21 00:00:00 F
    612 1993-10-19 00:00:00 M
    123 1993-03-02 00:00:00 M
    456 2019-10-19 00:00:00 F
    789 2019-11-04 00:00:00 M
    012 2000-10-02 00:00:00 M
```

Comment: Please show the results you want.  What is a "new ID"?  What do you mean by "append"?

Comment: So what is the problem here (apart from that you should be fixing the datatypes in `Table2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert the rows in `table2` that are not in `table1`, you can use `insert` with filtering logic:

```
insert into table1 (id, date, gen)
    select t2.id, t2.date, (case when gen = 1 then 'M' else 'F' end)
    from table2 t2
    where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

Comment: One of my gen is 'NULL'... What would be the result in the case condition? @Gordon

Comment: @Jammy . . . Given the above formulation it would be `NULL`.  You can instead use `(case when gen = 1 then 'M' when gen = 2 then 'F' end)`.  That will result in `NULL`.